# Retornar Array con sus valores usando Union Types

Tags: typescript

Debo de realizar una función que devuelva un array con los valores que les paso a sus parámetros, este método debe tener tipado el parámetro de entrada y el return, además de eso, el array debe hacer uso de los Union Type, hasta ahora tengo este código:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  profession: string;
}

const person: Person = (name: string, age: number, profession: string): Person[]  =>{
  let arr: Array<string|number> = [name, age, profession];
  return arr;       //Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'Person[]'

  //Creando el array de otra manera
  let arr1: ( string | number )[] = [name, age, profession];
  return arr1;      //Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'Person[]'
};

console.log(person( 'Juan', 35, 'Developer' ));
```

He intentado completar el array de dos formas posibles usando Union Types, de las dos maneras me presenta el error `Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'Person[]'`.

Probablemente esté retornando un valor que no es del tipo esperado o el array en ambos casos esté mal creado, lo que deseo saber es como podría solucionar este error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
type PersonArray = [a: string, b: number, c: string];

...

let data: PersonArray =[ 'Juan', 35, 'Developer']
```

O, usando la interfaz Person:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  profession: string;
}

type PersonArray = [a: string, b: number, c: string];

const toPersonArray =
     ( {name, age, profession}: Person): PersonArray => [ name, age, profession];

let p: Person = { name: 'Juan', age: 10, profession: 'Driver' };

let result: PersonArray = toPersonArray(p);
```

Puedes probar este código [aquí](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3EcnA1SQK5kBG0LYgAcoWGBAwZgOarXohmBAL4ECYAJ5CU6KNhABBKFDjrkAXmQBtOLLqMANMl7UQPflEcJb8hgF0WBAg4tMhgWDp6hsamZqzEyAAU%20KQUjuwQjiJiElI4StQROACUBZg4USbmAHxWJOQZbByZouKS0iD%20qgA2EGDIQqW6OOb4dRTUAOQAUlxwIBNpHNQAjAAMzdltMsgTACL0AG7QE8hKAT19UBJcXWCDkUaVFmGFBo-qCUJFLEEg2D0AOi6WAYCSuGBuYCKQA).

De este modo te aseguras de que el tipo resultante es un array donde el primer y el tercer elementos son un *string* y el segundo es un *number*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaracion!

Answer (score 0):

La interfaz es innecesaria para este caso, tú lo que quieres es devolver un array con todos los parámetros que pasas a la función usando Union Types verdad? de ser asi:

```
// funcion normal
function dataArray( name:string, age:number, profession:string ) : (number|string)[] { 
  let array : (number|string)[] = [name, age, profession];
  return array; // devuelve un array, cuyos elementos pueden ser number o string
}

// lo mismo pero en funcion flecha
const dataArrayArrow = ( name:string, age:number, profession:string ) : (number|string)[] => {
  let array : (number|string)[] = [name, age, profession];
  return array;
}

console.log(dataArray('Richard Harrisson', 45, 'Deal Maker on Pawn Stars'))
console.log(dataArrayArrow('Chumlee', 32, 'Idle on Pawn Stars'))
```

Tu al poner como tipo de dato de devolución `:Person[]` le estas diciendo que va a devolver un array de objetos que implementen la interfaz Person, pero tú no quieres eso por lo que veo.

Cualquier duda solo pregunta.

Comment: Funciona, pero puedes querer definir un array que sólo tenga 3 elementos y que sólo un elemento, el segundo, sea un número.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero de hecho sí, para este ejercicio la arrow function debe tener como parámetro la interfaz Person, por eso la definí al principio ```const person: **Person** = (name: string, age: number, profession: string): Person[]  =>{```.

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ veo que mencionas que al poner ```:Person[]``` al final ya estoy devolviendo un array, eso lo tengo claro, pero por lo que veo no basta con poner simplemente ```return name, age, profession;```

Comment: con poner :Person[] no estas devolviendo nada todavía, solo le indicas al interprete el tipo que quieres devolver, pero en si no devolves nada, ahí tienes una buena respuesta de @PabloLozano